# cuda streams , two kernels with same input

Tags: cuda

I want to use streams in my code , it's the first time I am using them.

I have 2 kernels which can run concurrently because they do different jobs.

But , they take the same input.If they could work on different parts of input I could use some offset but now?

```
int nStreams = 2;

for (int i=0;i<nStreams;i++)  {

cudaMemcpyAsync( devInput, hostInput, streamBytes , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice , stream[i] );

Kernel1<<<...,0,stream[i]>>>(devInput, devC);
Kernel2<<<...,0,stream[i+1]>>>(devInput , devR);

}
```

The problem is with this line:

```
cudaMemcpyAsync( devInput, hostInput, streamBytes , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice , stream[i] );
```

How can I use the same arrays to both kernels?

I thought to make a duplicate of them (hostInput , devInput) and use accordingly , but I am not sure if it is another way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a [stream sync point](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1geb3b2f88b7c1cff8b67a998a3a41c179) after your `cudaMemcpyAsync` line:

```
cudaMemcpyAsync( devInput, hostInput, streamBytes , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice , stream1 );
cudaStreamSynchronize(stream1);

Kernel1<<<...,0,stream1>>>(devInput, devC);
Kernel2<<<...,0,stream2>>>(devInput, devR);
```

Now the kernels are guaranteed not to launch until the `cudaMemcpyAsync` operation is complete, and it will then be valid for both to access the same `devInput` data.

Comment: :So , it doesn't matter if I use stream0 orstream 1 inside cudaMemcpyAsync (devInput....stream0) ,as long as I have the same stream number with cudaStreamSynchronize? Or I must use the first stream?Thank you!

Comment: Correct, the stream you use there does not matter (in this trivially simple example) as  long as you use the same stream for the blocking sync, because that will block until the copy is complete.  Thereafter, it also does not really matter which streams you use for the kernel calls (as long as they are separate from each other).

Comment: :Ok.Hmm , something last.I am running the code ,it shows some results but then "hangs" when I should take some other results later in the code (which depend from the output I am getting from the above kernels).Should I add another command  somewhere? I am using cudaDeviceSynchronize() after the kernel calls

Comment: George this is a new question.  SO Q+A is not a chat room.  And it's really not a personalized debugging service.  You haven't shown any of your code and you want me to tell you why it's hanging and how to fix it?  Please post a new question, following the advice for crisp, answerable questions I have given you previously.  Post a simple, complete reproducer of your hang. *NO* I am not asking for your code. *YES* it requires work on your part to create a simple reproducer.